# WebSocket vs Long Polling for Sync Server

Tags: javascript, android, websocket, socket.io, polling

We have a NodeJs application running in our server to serve more than 3000 Android client devices over the market as our own product.

All of our Android devices are 24/7 concurrently being connected with our NodeJs server to get the latest data and commands. We have developed an Android application for our device to connect with our Socket.IO server.

**Problem:** 
We are currently experiencing a huge bandwidth in our server network even there are no bulk data exchanges happened between server and clients, we only use the data to view the count of connected devices at the same time.

**Question:** 
Let me give you an example use case similar to our real scenario, let's say we have more than 3000 Android devices which are fixed in many bus-stops to show the next bus available but at the moment we are not pushing any data although the Socket.IO connection opens.

I would like to know the best solution and architecture for this use-case and I'm seeking the best recommendation over WebSocket vs Long-Polling for this situation.

As I researched the WebSocket can save more data over Long-Polling, I need suggestions on this.

Thanks in advance.

Example server:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.send('Hello!');
  socket.on('message', (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: What language for backend and client end? Otherwise I'd recommend TCP sockets and use the servers time stamp to know when a device last connected.

Comment: I'd go sockets over long polling, long polling, if I remember correctly, uses HTTP which is fairly bulky when compared to TCP. So TCP is likely your best solution.

Comment: @WLGfx I'm using Nodejs

Comment: @Ameer can I know some explaination

Comment: For NodeJS, the `net` module is probably the easiest way to go. The Android devices can use the TCP connection to poll, get the result and then disconnect until the next time they need to connect.